# Why does solana use the term "authority" instead of "owner"?

Tags: program

In ethereum, usually admin rights are defined by the term "owner". For example, many libraries follow this convention such as OpenZeppelin's `Ownable` contracts. Why in solana, are admin rights designated by the term "authority"? For example, `mint authority` etc. What is the etymology and why change the convention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

‘Owner,‘ where accounts are concerned, typically indicates which *program* owns a given account. Only the owning program can write data to that account.

‘Authority’ is a higher-level concept. Within the context of a mint account, for instance, tokens can only be minted when the ‘mint authority’ signs the mint transaction.

At the lowest level, however, the Token Program is the owner of the mint account itself, and has exclusive write access to its on-chain data. Here’s how it goes:

1. The mint instruction executes inside the Token Program
2. The Token Program asserts that the mint authority noted in the mint account has signed the transaction
3. The Token Program, because it has exclusive write access to the mint account, is able to increase the supply in the mint account.

Naming is hard.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's due to "Owner" already being used to refer to owning accounts which isn't always synonymous with admin rights. In the example you gave, Account `A` could be the **owner** of Token Account `TA`, however the ultimate admin could still be held by a seperate **freeze authority** `B`, as they could choose to freeze `A`'s tokens inside `TA` for example.